why spark streaming transform casue Task not serializable error

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object SparkStreaming {


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sc = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Dstream")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
    // ssc.socketStream()
    //val textStream = ssc.textFileStream("file://D:\\spark\\scala-learn\\data")
    val textStream = ssc.textFileStream("file:///D:/spark/scala-learn/data")

    // textStream.map(line => line).print()
    def reverseString(input: String): String = {
      if (input.isEmpty) "" 
      else reverseString(input.tail) + input.head
    }
    def removeEndCommas(s: String): String = {
      if (s.startsWith(",")) removeEndCommas(s.substring(1))
      else if (s.endsWith(",")) removeEndCommas(s.substring(0, s.length - 1))
      else s
    }
    textStream.transform(rdd => {
   //   rdd.map(reverseString)   //with this line work fine 
      rdd.map(removeEndCommas)   // with this line cause error  below 
    }).print()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

  }
}

error info :
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2356)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$map$1(RDD.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:395)
    at com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$.$anonfun$main$1(SparkStreaming.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$transform$2(DStream.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$transform$4(DStream.scala:682)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.compute(TransformedDStream.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$getOrCompute$3(DStream.scala:343)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$getOrCompute$2(DStream.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(TransformedDStream.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$getOrCompute$1(DStream.scala:342)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.$anonfun$generateJobs$2(DStreamGraph.scala:123)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.$anonfun$generateJobs$1(JobGenerator.scala:252)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$, value: com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$@4249e338)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic com/zjjr/bigdata/bd232/SparkStreaming$.$anonfun$main$2:(Lcom/zjjr/bigdata/bd232/SparkStreaming$;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;, instantiatedMethodType=(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;, numCaptured=1])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$$$Lambda$774/1623867887, com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$$$Lambda$774/1623867887@36d4ae09)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:413)
    ... 37 more
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2356)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$map$1(RDD.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:395)
    at com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$.$anonfun$main$1(SparkStreaming.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$transform$2(DStream.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$transform$4(DStream.scala:682)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.compute(TransformedDStream.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$getOrCompute$3(DStream.scala:343)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$getOrCompute$2(DStream.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(TransformedDStream.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$getOrCompute$1(DStream.scala:342)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.$anonfun$generateJobs$2(DStreamGraph.scala:123)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.$anonfun$generateJobs$1(JobGenerator.scala:252)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$, value: com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$@4249e338)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic com/zjjr/bigdata/bd232/SparkStreaming$.$anonfun$main$2:(Lcom/zjjr/bigdata/bd232/SparkStreaming$;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;, instantiatedMethodType=(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;, numCaptured=1])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$$$Lambda$774/1623867887, com.zjjr.bigdata.bd232.SparkStreaming$$$Lambda$774/1623867887@36d4ae09)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:413)
    ... 37 more


reverseString and removeEndCommas  has not logic difference, why different output
